How do I solve the blinking of the cursor in terminal?
I used a grep an incomplete grep command "grep hello" now the cursor moved to the next line and it is doing nothing but sitting there only. Can't even exit out of it.
Now whatever I type it just get printed out. Screenshot

see what's wrong with my grep command? in particular this answer mentioning Ctrl-D
